# Illegal string offset error in codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, associative-array

im doing a PHP project using codeigniter 2.1.2 , using mySql database on WAMP, i have stumbled upon the following problem:

Here is my model

```
function loadUserData() {
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ?";
    $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, $this->session->userdata('username'));

    if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }

}
```

The controller

```
function profile_access() {
    if ($this -> session -> userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        $this->load-> model('profile_model');
        $uData['rows']=$this->profile_model->loadUserData();
        $this->load->view('profile_view',$uData);

    } else {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"You need to provide your credentials first.\");</script>";
        redirect('login_controller/index');
    }
}
```

and the view

```
<?php
      foreach($rows as $r){
              echo print_r($r);
              echo $r[username]->username; //line no. 81 in my code
            }
?>
```

the `print_r($r)` from view gives me the following errors:

```
alphaomega1
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username'
Filename: views/profile_view.php
Line Number: 81


A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal string offset 'username'
Filename: views/profile_view.php
Line Number: 81


A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/profile_view.php
Line Number: 81
```

I expect the above code to return only "alphaomega" which is the username in the database. it is however displayed, but i dont know why i'm getting those errors. would appreciate some help with this. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view:

```
foreach($rows as $r){
     echo $r->username;
}
```

In your model:

```
function loadUserData() {
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $this->session->userdata('username'));

    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Yan . it worked. But, in my model,wasn't i doing the same thing?, i was just checking whether there are any rows returned or not. what exactly is the difference if u wont mind explaining.

Comment: Glad it helped. The difference is that in your model you were erasing `$data` with each iteration (`$data = $row`) which made the result a single row. It is a waste of processing time and the outcome is different. If you want to get a single row you can use `$query->row()`.

Comment: Another difference: In your function if the number of rows returned in query is zero your function doesn't return a value.

Comment: thanks! I also found that if in my model instead of writing `$data = $row` if i write `$data[]=$row` and changing the view as you suggested. it works.

Comment: Whats the benefit of doing it over simply returning `$query->result()`?

Comment: `$query -> result()` seems to be the better way to do it. Thanks!